# Python copy a list and edit this copy

Tags: python, list, copy

Im trying to copy a list and then change something in that copy, but it always changes in both lists.

```
_team1_picks = team1_picks.copy()
_team2_picks = team2_picks.copy()
for karte in _team1_picks:
    print(team1_picks, _team1_picks)
    karte[2],karte[3] = karte[3],karte[2]
    print(team1_picks, _team1_picks)
for karte in _team2_picks:
    print(team2_picks, _team2_picks)
    karte[2],karte[3] = karte[3],karte[2]
    print(team1_picks, _team1_picks)
```

This is my code and the output is:

```
[['Kafe', 1, 7, 3]] [['Kafe', 1, 7, 3]]
[['Kafe', 1, 3, 7]] [['Kafe', 1, 3, 7]]
[['Oregon', 1, 7, 5]] [['Oregon', 1, 7, 5]]
[['Oregon', 1, 5, 7]] [['Oregon', 1, 5, 7]]
```

I also tried to slice the lists with

```
_team1_picks = team1_picks[:]
_team2_picks = team2_picks[:]
```

but with the same result.

On another occasion it works with `.copy()`:

```
_decider = decider.copy()
_decider[1],_decider[2] = decider[2],decider[1]
```

Here only the `_decider` list is getting modified.
Now im confused why it works one time but not the othert time, and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the things you're doing are just copying the top-level list.  This is known as a shallow copy.  If you want to recursively copy *all* lists, including nested sublists, you can use a deep copy:

```
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

This will recursively copy all lists and sublists.

Answer (score 1):

you are just modifying the iterator object not the element inside `_team1_picks`

with `indexing` you can do this as

```
for index, karte in enumerate(_team1_picks):
    print(team1_picks, _team1_picks)
    _team1_picks[index][2], _team1_picks[index][3] = _team1_picks[index][3], _team1_picks[index][2]
    print(team1_picks, _team1_picks)
```

do this similiar for other list